# Constructing a cryptocurrency momentum factor

Tags: momentum, cryptocurrency

This might be a very trivial question, but I simply can't find a practical answer anywhere.

I am writing my Master's Thesis, and in this regard, i'm investigating the cross-sectional momentum effect in the cryptocurrency market, using the methodologies of Jegadeesh & Titman (1993). I am using past *J* (1, 2, 3 & 4) value-weighted weekly log returns in order to sort the currencies' subsequent 1-week log return in 5 equal-weighted quantile portfolios in ascending order, such that P5 is the winner portfolio and P1 is the loser portfolio.

**Example**:
I calculate each coin's log return from *t-1* to *t* (past 1-week log return), and then sort each of these past returns (every week) in ascending order. Then, for every week, I find each of the coin's subsequent 1-week log return from *t* to *t+1*. I will then sort the coins in 5 portfolios (based on the past 1-week return), in which each of the portfolios will contain an equal-weighted average of the subsequent 1-week return of the coins contained in the specific portfolio.

My question is how I can construct a momentum factor in lines with how [Kenneth R. French](https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/det_mom_factor.html) does it? Do I use the past 1-week returns, or do I use the subsequent 1-week returns to construct the momentum factor?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this yet? I am also working on cryptocurrency momentum.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa No clear answer yet. But as far a I understand it, I must construct the momentum factor using the subsequent K-week returns. 

Say I am working with 5 coins. In week *t*, I calculate each coin's cumulative log returns from *t-J* to *t*. Then, I sort these returns in ascending order, such that the coin with the highest past return will be P5, and P1 is the coin with the lowest past return. I long P5 and short P1 at time *t*, and hold this position until time *t+K*. 

Then, to construct the momentum factor, I will use *t* to *t+K* returns, and **not** the *t-J* to *t* returns.

Comment: Thank you. Here is one link I have come across https://teddykoker.com/2019/05/momentum-strategy-from-stocks-on-the-move-in-python/